# How do I plot many arrows in a sphere?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a lot of arrows in a sphere (3D-Plot). That is not a problem with a small number of `Arrows`; for a few I can do than something like this:

```
Show[
  Graphics3D[{Thickness[Large], Arrowheads[Large],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, 
    Axes -> True], 
  SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2*Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]]
```

However, I want do something like a for-loop to plot many `Arrows`

```
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/i, (1-i)/5, (1-i)/5}}]
```

I have tried to paste for loop in many places of my graphics code, but without success. How should I build that code?

Comment: For loops do not create arrays. They repeat an action several times. Try using Table instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Table when you want to create a list of values.

```
myarrows = Table[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/i, (1 - i)/5, (1 - i)/5}}], {i, 1, 10}]

Graphics3D[myarrows]
```

For loops only repeat an evaluation over and over - it doesn't put the result of the evaluations into a list.

Comment: One might put an Append[] in the middle of the loop, or even use Sow[] and Reap[] in connection with a loop, in order to generate a list. However, there are few scenarios in which either of these is better than using Table[] as you suggest.

Comment: Sow and Reap hadn't occurred to me an a quick solution here until just now actually. I feel bad that I don't use it pr functions like it more often.